# working with php decbin function

Tags: php

I'm so new in php. I want to ask for decbin function in PHP 
let say I have this code :

```
 <?php
    $input= 8;
    for($i=0;$i<$input ; $i++){  
     echo decbin($i)."<br>";
    }
 ?>
```

then the output will be like this:

```
0 
1
10
11
100
101
110
111
```

But I want to make the output like this

```
000
100
100
110
100
101
110
111
```

Any suggested for this?

Comment: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) is an awesome reference and has great user added snippets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use str_pad

```
echo str_pad(decbin($i), 3, '0') . '<br/>';
```

http://sg.php.net/str_pad

Your complete code should look like:

```
 <?php
    $input= 8;
    for($i=0;$i<$input ; $i++){  
     echo str_pad(decbin($i), 3, '0') . '<br/>';
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[str_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) should work

`echo str_pad(decbin($i), 3 , '0');  // defaults to right padding`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the [str_pad() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php); this code works fine for me:

```
<?php
    $input= 8;
    for($i=0;$i<$input ; $i++){  
        echo(str_pad(decbin($i),3,0).'<br />');
    }
?>
```